# how to create nuspec file in specific folder?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, nuspec

I tried to create .nuspec file in a different folder by giving path but 
it is giving me error

```
Nuget.exe spec ..\MYDEMOFOLDER
Nuget.exe pack ..\MYDEMOFOLDER\MYPROJECT.csproj
pause
```

want to create `MYPROJECT.nuspec` in `..\MYDEMOFOLDER` folder location

```
getting error to create nuspec file 
The package ID '..\MYDEMOFOLDER' contains invalid characters. Examples of valid package IDs in
clude 'MyPackage' and 'MyPackage.Sample'.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately `nuget.exe spec` doesn't work like that. It expects a package ID.

If you need to create a *nuspec* in a given folder, you will need to change to that directory.

```
pushd ..\MYDEMOFOLDER          // switch to new directory (remember current)
nuget spec MYPROJECT           // create MYPROJECT.nuspec file
nuget pack MYPROJECT.csproj    // pack MYPROJECT.csproj
popd                           // return to previous directory
```

> NOTE: If you're going to pack a project file, you don't need to create a *nuspec* file, as nuget will create one automatically.

Answer (score 1):

1. navigate to the directory you want to create the file
2. download this [nuget exe](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) in the directory
3. cd to the directory on command line
4. use the command "nuget spec project.csproj"
5. check your directory for the generated nuspec file

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate .nupkg file using below command

> nuget pack MYPROJECT.csproj

2. change the .nupkg file extension to .zip.
3. Open the zip you will see the .nuspec file.

Answer (score 0):

Dotnet has quite confusing similar arguments

```
--output
```

is used for output for build = input for nuget pack

```
/p:OutputPath=
```

is used as output folder of nuget pack itself

Example:

```
dotnet pack -c Release -p:PackageVersion=1.2.3 YourProject.csproj --no-build --output c:\outputofbuild  /p:OutputPath=c:\outputfornuget
```